# How do I find type of value entered from the keyboard?

Tags: c#, console-application, typeof

How do I use a method to display the types of values entered from the keyboard in the C# consol application?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int yas;
    Console.Write("Enter Your Age: ");

    yas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("You're {0} years old.", yas);

}
```

In the application in the example, I only want your user to enter numerical data, but I tried to do it with typeof it gives an error. Can you help me?

I don't want to change the type of variable. I want to make your user want value again instead of int. parse error when entering a value

Comment: You should use `if(int.TryParse(Console.Readline()) { /// success } else { /// failure }`

Comment: [Int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I don't want to change the type of variable. I want to make your user want value again instead of int.parse error when entering a value

Comment: You can actually tell the type of variable by carefully parsing and re-parsing the input. Did `bool.TryParse` succeed, then its a bool. Did `int.TryParse` succeed? What about `decimal.TryParse` (you need to do the `int` call first). If nothing else, then it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to make your user want value again instead of int.parse error when entering a value*

You can kee asking for input until it's correct using the method mentioned in the comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int yas;

    do { // until the user input is valid, keep asking
        Console.Write("Yaşınız Giriniz: ");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out yas));

    Console.WriteLine("Demek {0} yaşınızdasınız", yas);
}
```